# PowerBI: Groupby Column and Count as a Measure

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataframe with two categorical columns, col A and col B. I want to generate counts of *each category of col B* while grouping by col A. I want the output as a `measure`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure =
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( tbl[colB] ), ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[colA] ) )
```

Comment: Apologies, this works, but I forgot to mention that I want the counts of each category of col B -- is there a way to accommodate this in a measure, or perhaps to make its own column? I need this to work with DirectQuery.

Comment: So you want the count to be grouped by colA and colB?

Comment: Count of each category in category B, while grouped on category A

Comment: Can you possibly provide a sample data and expected output so that I can better understand this.

Comment: I modified yours to do something like this, downside is having to make N many of these: `CALCULATE(COUNT('NICE tbl'[colb])+0,ALLEXCEPT('tbl'','tbl'[colb]),'tbl'[cola]="value")`

Comment: If `colA` is the axis in the pivot/viz, why are you explicitly mentioning `'tbl'[cola]="value"`. There is no need. But if you could have a provided a small sample data we could have addressed very quickly rather than guessing here.